# How to host activex control for to render html on window using Visual c++ (x64) application

Tags: winapi, activex, webbrowser-control, web-hosting, ihtmldocument2

I am trying to render a html file in my own create window using Visual c++(x64). I have done every thing I just need some mechanism to display html file in my own window.I have html file contents stored in a buffer (and i am sure about that because i have the same html code in my buffer which I can see when I open that file in notepad, so the only thing i have to do is to get a way to render that html file in my window)

On a random search on google i have been aware that i need to host an activex control but i don't know how to do that.Yes ofcourse there are some samples availble on internet but they are not for Visual c++ (x64 MFC application).

What i have in mind is that
(1.) i will create a dialog using-

```
     HINSTANCE   g_hInst2     = NULL;
                    m_hwndPreview= CreateDialogParam( g_hInst2,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_HTML_DIALOG), m_hwndParent,(DLGPROC)DialogProc, (LPARAM)this);
        //I have not implemented the part below (its just idea that what should i do?? please correct me
// if my idea is wrong)I have not implemented it because when i create dialog using CreateDialogParam(...)  when i debug it i get m_hwndPreview=0000000000000 
                // and once if m_hwndPreview is done successfully i have assumed the code below in my
// mind to achieve my target. please correct me if i am wrong ??

                    CWebBrowser2 * pBrowse = (CWebBrowser2 *) GetDlgItem(IDC_EXPLORER1);
                    COleVariant sLoc("http://localhost");
                    pBrowse->Navigate2(sLoc, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            //after that
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    ShowWindow(m_hwndPreview, SW_SHOW);
                    UpdateWindow( m_hwndPreview );
                }
```

Am i right ??

Please answer the two questions (1.) Why m_hwndPreview=00000000000 ?? because i have created a dialog(IDD_HTML_DIALOG) using resource editor and inserted a activex contol (Microsoft web browser) and it is done succesfully because i can see in my file resource.h (I have #define IDC_EXPLORER1 1046) so its sure that it has been done.
There may be some problem in g_hInst2. i don't undersatnd it properly.
(2.) Is my approach to achieve my target is correct ?? if i _hwndPreview is done succesfully then the code which i have assumed will work or not ?? is my approach correct ??

Comment: Get last error says.....?

Comment: @ Xearinox It says- hrhr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError()); on debugging hr = 0x80070715 The specified resource type cannot be found in the image file.

Comment: any idea why ?? but this time i have used m_hwndPreview3 = CreateDialog( NULL,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_HTML_DIALOG), m_hwndParent,(DLGPROC)DialogProc); (not createdialogparam,but its still equal)

Comment: Why is g_hInst2 NULL?

Comment: @ Xearinox ghinst2 is null because i have intialized it with NULL. but on debugging it also gives 0000000000 just as m_hwndPreview gives 00000000000 . Is it responsible for my problem ???

Comment: @ Xearinox  in short i want to ask you that is my approach to do that is correct or not ?? what do you think ??

Comment: Yes. Try use g_hInst2 = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

Comment: now on debugging g_hInst2 = 0x00000000ffa40000 {unused=9460301 } but m_hwndPreview = 0x0000000000000000 {unused=??? }. i don't know why it gives zero value and error = 0x80070715 The specified resource type cannot be found in the image file. any idea why ??

Comment: for more information i also want to tell you in the same program i have created one more dialog which is meant to display image. Does taht create problem ?? and this g_hInst2 is for render a html file on the created dialog. please help me in taking out of this problem it am stuck here for a long time..I thnakyou so much for this.

Comment: and gor your help i want to tell you the value of both the g_hinst(for image rendering in display) and g_hinst2(for this case) on debugging are 
g_hInst = 0x000007fef5d70000 {unused=9460301 }
g_hInst2 = 0x00000000ffa40000 {unused=9460301 }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35070/discussion-between-shekhar-singh-shekhawat-and-xearinox)